# Call function in other child component when mouse up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouseevent, react-redux, ref

In `ReactJS` I m trying to call a function in a child component but from another child component. Basically, when the event `mouseup` occurs, I would like to trigger a function that is in another component.

This image shows what I am trying to do:

[image]

I m working with `react-redux`, so the thing I want to do is dispatch an action when the `mouseup` event occurs in the `child_2 component` and this dispatch should trigger another action inside the `child_1 component`.

Does someone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about redux, but ideally how it should it work is that the state needs to be communicated through the parent. So how you can implement it is like:

1. Call the function in the child_1 component on change of a props value, say 'flag1'.
2. Update this flag1 value in parent component through a function call from child_2 component whenever there is mouseup event.

Example:

```
class Child1 extends React.Component {

    ......
    Based on props.flag value do whatever you want
    ......

}

class Child2 extends React.Component {

......
call this.props.updateStatus on mouseUp with argument
......

}

class Parent extends React.Component {
    updateStatus(status) {
        this.state.flag=status;
    }

    render() {

      <Child1 flag={this.state.flag}>
      </Child1>

      <Child2 updateStatus={this.updateStatus.bind(this)>
      </Child2>
    }

}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
class Child1 extends React.Component {
    ....
    someFunction = () => {

    };
    ...
};

const Child2 = ({ onClick }) => {
    return (<div onClick={onClick}>click me!</div>);
};

class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.child1Ref = null;
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>
            <Child1 ref={(c) => { this.child1Ref = c; } />
            <Child2
                onClick={() => {
                    if (this.child1Ref) {
                        this.child1Ref.someFunction();
                    }
                });
            />
        </div>);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help, I did no try this method but saw similar ways of doing. However with Typescript it gets a bit more complicated to work with refs... well this is what I thought